# Grouping an array by comparing 2 adjacent elements

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of objects and I would like to group them based on the difference between the attributes of 2 adjacent elements. The array is already sorted by that attribute. For instance:

**Original array:**

`array = [a, b, c, d, e]`

and

```
a.attribute = 1
b.attribute = 3
c.attribute = 6
d.attribute = 9
e.attribute = 10
```

If I want to group the elements such that the difference between the attributes of 2 adjacent elements are less or equal than 2, the result should look like so:

**END RESULT**

`result_array = [[a, b], [c], [d, e]]`

**WHAT I HAVE**

```
def group_elements_by_difference(array, difference)
    result_array = []
    subgroup = []
    last_element_attribute = array.first.attribute
    array.each do |element|
      if element.attribute <= (last_element_attribute + difference)
        subgroup << element
      else
        #add the subgroup to the result_array
        result_array << subgroup
        subgroup = []
        subgroup << element
      end
      #update last_element_attribute
      last_element_attribute = element.attribute
    end
    result_array << subgroup
end
```

**QUESTION**

Is there a built in function in Ruby 1.9.3, such as `group_by` that could replace my `group_elements_by_difference`?

Comment: `slice_before.with_index`?

Comment: `slice_before` with state should do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following Jan Dvorak's suggestion, this solution uses slice_before and a hash to keep the state:

```
class GroupByAdjacentDifference < Struct.new(:data)
  def group_by(difference)
    initial = { prev: data.first }

    data.slice_before(initial) do |item, state|
      prev, state[:prev] = state[:prev], item
      value_for(item) - value_for(prev) > difference
    end.to_a
  end

  def value_for(elem)
    elem.attribute
  end
end

require 'rspec/autorun'

describe GroupByAdjacentDifference do

  let(:a) { double("a", attribute: 1) }
  let(:b) { double("b", attribute: 3) }
  let(:c) { double("c", attribute: 6) }
  let(:d) { double("d", attribute: 9) }
  let(:e) { double("e", attribute: 10) }

  let(:data) { [a, b, c, d, e] }
  let(:service) { described_class.new(data) }

  context "#group_by" do
    it "groups data by calculating adjacent difference" do
      expect(service.group_by(2)).to eq([[a, b], [c], [d, e]])
    end
  end
end
```

which gives

```
$ ruby group_by_adjacent_difference.rb
.

Finished in 0.0048 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

In alternative, local variables could also be used to keep state, although I find it a bit harder to read:

```
class GroupByAdjacentDifference < Struct.new(:data)
  def group_by(difference)
    tmp = data.first

    data.slice_before do |item|
      tmp, prev = item, tmp
      value_for(item) - value_for(prev) > difference
    end.to_a
  end

  def value_for(elem)
    elem.attribute
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

The following uses numerals directly, but the algorithm should be the same as when you do it with attributes. It assumes that all numerals are greater than `0`. If not, then replace it with something that works.

```
array = [1, 3, 6, 9, 10]

[0, *array].each_cons(2).slice_before{|k, l| l - k > 2}.map{|a| a.map(&:last)}
# => [[1, 3], [6], [9, 10]]
```

With attributes, do `l.attribute`, etc., and replace `0` with a dummy element whose attribute is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
array = [1, 3, 6, 9, 10]
prev = array[0]
p array.slice_before{|el| prev,el = el,prev; prev-el > 2}.to_a

# => [[1, 3], [6], [9, 10]]
```